# KVO white balance gains always nil

Tags: swift3, key-value-observing, avcapturedevice

I'm observing changes in some AVCaptureDevice properties, one of these is white balance gains. My code is:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if let newValue = change?[.newKey] as? NSValue {
        if context == &DeviceWhiteBalanceGainsContext {
            var gains : AVCaptureWhiteBalanceGains? = nil
            newValue.getValue(&gains)
            if let g = gains {
                temperatureValue = Double(videoDevice.temperatureAndTintValues(forDeviceWhiteBalanceGains: g).temperature)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it never passes the `if let g = gains` because the `gains` is nil. What's even weirder is when I put breakpoint on that line the debug windows shows me that `gains` is not nil and valid but in the console `po gains` would output nil and the code never passes the condition.